# How to collapse Modal Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

#### How to collapse Modal Material UI?

I'm using a Modal component mui and want to collapse the modal window? Tell me how to do it?

Comment: Please do not misuse or overuse the bold

Answer (score 0):

You mean close it?

Well, if that's the case this is how you do it.

```
<Dialog
 onClose={() => setModal(false)}
>
<your divs here/>
</Dialog>
```